# Laravel delete all directories that are older than a certain date

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to write an artisan command that deletes any folders that are 50 or more days old. I am unable to do thiswith timestamps, but the folder names are labelled with the date i.e 2022-01-14 (Y-m-d)

```
collections/2022-01-14
collections/2022-01-13
collections/2022-01-12
```

This is what I currently have, but it is not doing anything and not returning any errors, it just doesnt work

```php
collect(Storage::directories('collections/'))
    ->each(function ($directory) {
        if ($directory < now()->subDays(50)->format('Y-m-d')) {
            Storage::deleteDirectory($directory);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should parse $directory to a Carbon instance first. Then use Carbon::lte function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a string with another string, use Carbon logic instead. Parse the directory name to a Carbon instance, and use less than equal `lte()` to compare.

```
collect(Storage::directories('collections/'))
    ->each(function ($directory) {
        $directoryDate = Str::after($directory, '/');
        if (Carbon::parse(directoryDate)->lte(now()->subDays(50))) {
            Storage::deleteDirectory($directory);
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

Directory came with full path, finding everything after `'/'` would get you the date part. Using the string helper `after()`.

Comment: Thou with your string comparison should provide a result, so maybe the problem lies another place

Comment: Ohhh .. If i echo out $directory, it displays as `collections/2022-01-14` .. Do you know if there is any way to only display the actual date in the directory name?

Comment: Probably not, but split the string and you should golden updating the answer now :)